How to change editor to director in a specific BibLaTeX entry
I got this particular bib entry
@Book{1999Gramatica-Descriptiv,
author = {}, 
title = {Gramática Descriptiva de la Lengua Española}, 
volume = {1, 2, 3}, 
pages = {}, 
editor = {Bosque, Ignacio and Demonte, Violeta}, 
publisher = {RAE Espasa}, 
address = {Madrid}, 
year = {1999}, 
abstract = {}, 
keywords = {description, spanish, grammar, curso-lengua, curso-sintaxis}}

I would like to change it in order to use director(s) instead of editor(s) but only in this particular entry to use with BibLaTeX and biber with the authoryear style.
Thank you very much in advance

One way is to use the editortype field in the entry and customize the string for this editor type. Below I have used compiler as it seems closest to director, other predefined editortypes in BibLaTeX are founder, continuator, redactor, reviser, collaborator, organizer.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Book{1999Gramatica-Descriptiv,
author = {}, 
title = {Gramática Descriptiva de la Lengua Española}, 
volume = {1, 2, 3}, 
pages = {}, 
editor = {Bosque, Ignacio and Demonte, Violeta}, 
editortype = {compiler},
publisher = {RAE Espasa},
address = {Madrid}, 
year = {1999}, 
abstract = {}, 
keywords = {description, spanish, grammar, curso-lengua, curso-sintaxis}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
compiler = {director},
compilers = {directors}
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{1999Gramatica-Descriptiv}
\printbibliography
\end{document}



Thank you. It worked
